# Passing arguments with SudzC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, web-services, sudzc

I discover yesterday a library to use WebServices with Objective-C : Sudzc.
I try to use this and i have a problem with parameters in call methods.
I call like this :

```
SDZMobileActionsBeanService *service = [SDZMobileActionsBeanService service];
[service getListMobileMenuItemByMobileApplicationId:self action:@selector(getApp:) arg0:15];
```

arg0 is my argument and when soap transmit request to my jboss server i see that arg0 is null.
I try also with wsdl2objc library it's the same result.
I don't know why, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: As what type is arg0 declared?

Comment: @rudy velthuis arg0 is a long

Comment: @Rudy Valthuis it's the same if arg0 is a NSString

Answer (score 0):

you might need to convert string to int or vise versa.  check the generated code to see what sudzc declared it as.

```
NSString *string = blah;
int value = [string intValue];
```